# discrete function by using VBA

Tags: excel, montecarlo, vba

I am trying to create Discrete function by using VBA code.
It works sometime, but I also received "Subscript of range error" message. Anyone can figure out the reason?

```
Function Discrete6()    
    Dim value As Variant, prob As Variant, i As Integer
    Dim uniform As Double, cumProb As Variant

    value = Array(5, 10, 12)
    prob = Array(0.2, 0.3, 0.5)
    uniform = Rnd
    cumProb = prob(1)

    i = 1
    Do Until cumProb > uniform
        i = i + 1
        cumProb = cumProb + prob(i)
    Loop

    Discrete6 = value(i)
End Function
```

Comment: What stops your `i` from growing beyond `UBound(prob)`?

Comment: Thanks GSerg, I have three numbers including 5, 10 and 12 and the corresponding weighting of those number is 0.2, 0.3, and 0.5. My function is to return a random variable either 5 or 10 or 12 based on weighting.

Comment: On first iteration your `Do` loop requests `prob(2)`, which is the last element of `prob`, unless you have `Option Base 1`, which I assume you don't. If it happens that a second iteration is required, you request `prob(3)` and get the index out of bounds error.

Comment: Thanks, I do have option 1 in my overall function. This is part of my function, I am just wondering why I got the message. Thanks

Comment: @ShanmengWei to make sure I understand what you are trying to achieve with your function. If `Rnd` is from 0 to 0.2 then return 5, if `Rnd` is from 0.2 to 0.5 return 10, and if `Rnd` is from 0.5 to 1 return 12 ? this is the result you want ?

Comment: @ShaiRado, Yes, thats the results I want to achieve, it works sometimes, just wondering why.

Comment: @ShanmengWei see the code below if it works, it fits a case with array of 3 members

Comment: @ShaiRado, Thanks, but I cant see your codes?

Comment: @ShanmengWei try at the code below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following modification is a little dirty, but it works in your specific case (an array with 3 members).

```
Function Discrete6()

Dim value As Variant, prob As Variant, i As Integer
Dim uniform As Double, cumProb As Variant

value = Array(5, 10, 12)
prob = Array(0.2, 0.5, 1)
uniform = Rnd

Select Case uniform
    Case Is <= prob(0)
        Discrete6 = value(0)
    Case Is > prob(1)
        Discrete6 = value(2)
    Case Else
        Discrete6 = value(1)
End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Shai, I think it works and crack on the problems. I will take you suggestion, but I will still try to figure out about my own way. Have a good day!!!

Comment: @VBA_Beginner if my code solved your errors, then please mark as the answer and upvote.